# How fetch value DateTime format from SQL Server database in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, casting, format

I have this ASP.NET code that fetches all data from a SQL Server database table:

```
connection.Open();

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT top 10  [Raspberry_ID],[Raspberry_name],[Speaker_Name],[Speaker_Volume],[Speaker_Mute],[Speaker_Status],[Speaker_Availability],[currently_playing_song],[Date_Time]  FROM [ISH_EDVBetreuung].[dbo].[Raspi_speaker]", connection))
{
    // Make sure the command object does not already have
    // a notification object associated with it.
    command.Notification = null;
    SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBase"].ConnectionString);

    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        connection.Open();

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                     .Select(x => new Raspi_speaker()
                                  {
                                      Raspberry_ID = x.GetString(0),
                                      Raspberry_name = x.GetString(1),
                                      Speaker_Name = x.GetString(2),
                                      Speaker_Volume = x.GetInt32(3),
                                      Speaker_Mute = x.GetBoolean(4),
                                      Speaker_Status = x.GetBoolean(5),
                                      Speaker_Availability = x.GetBoolean(6),
                                      currently_playing_song = x.GetString(7),
                                      Date_Time = x.GetDateTime(8)
                                   }).ToList();

}
```

And view code in index is :

```
for (var i = 0; i < newdata.length; i++) 
{
    var D_T = new Date()

    rows.push(' <tr><td>' + newdata[i].Raspberry_ID + '</td><td>' + newdata[i].Raspberry_name + '</td><td>' + newdata[i].Speaker_Name + '</td><td>' + newdata[i].Speaker_Volume + '</td><td>' + newdata[i].Speaker_Mute + '</td><td>' + newdata[i].Speaker_Status + '</td><td>' + newdata[i].Speaker_Availability + '</td><td>' + newdata[i].currently_playing_song + '</td><td>' + newdata[i].Date_Time  + '</td></tr>');
}

$tbl.append(rows.join(''));
```

But my problem is with DataTime value - when I run the code, I get DataTime in browser like this:

```
ID  Name    Last Executed Date  Status
100000008d98f051    raspberrypi(Musiktest)  Bedroom 2   false   true    true    Fix You - Rebeca Hope.mp3   /Date(1634638560000)/
100000008d98f051    raspberrypi(Musiktest)  Office  2   false   true    true    Fix You - Rebeca Hope.mp3   /Date(1634638561000)/
10000000c25bbdfb    Crea_RASPI SONOS    Holzbox Eingang 8   false   true    true    Je ne peux pas oublier - PaTi-PaMi.mp3  /Date(1634638562000)/
10000000c25bbdfb    Crea_RASPI SONOS    Holzbox Eingang2    11  false   true    true    Je ne peux pas oublier - PaTi-PaMi.mp3  /Date(1634638564000)/
10000000c25bbdfb    Crea_RASPI SONOS    Holzbox 8   false   true    true    Je ne peux pas oublier - PaTi-PaMi.mp3  /Date(1634638567000)/
100000008d98f051    raspberrypi(Musiktest)  Bedroom 2   false   true    true    Fix You - Rebeca Hope.mp3   /Date(1634638624000)/
100000008d98f051    raspberrypi(Musiktest)  Office  2   false   true    true    Fix You - Rebeca Hope.mp3   /Date(1634638626000)/
10000000c25bbdfb    Crea_RASPI SONOS    Holzbox Hinten  16  false   true    true    Je ne peux pas oublier - PaTi-PaMi.mp3  /Date(1634638631000)/
10000000c25bbdfb    Crea_RASPI SONOS    Holzbox Eingang 8   false   true    true    Je ne peux pas oublier - PaTi-PaMi.mp3  /Date(1634638634000)/
10000000c25bbdfb    Crea_RASPI SONOS    Holzbox Eingang2    11  false   true    true    Je ne peux pas oublier - PaTi-PaMi.mp3  /Date(1634638636000)/
```

All the values are right only DateTime like so `/Date(1634638636000)/`

I hope your help thank you so much

Comment: Which type is this property Date_Time. Which type is the database column in which you are storing this data?

Comment: column type ist DateTime in dataBase and this Date_time is property in object his name is Raspi_speaker and also in this object his Type is DateTime like column

Comment: We'd need more shared code, from what you shared so far it's not possible to see what's wrong.

Comment: @MohamadEibo try this approach DATEADD(S, CONVERT(int,LEFT([DATETIME], 10)), '1970-01-01') 
Convert the timestamp to int then convert it to DateTime